# SSHing between EC2 instances without having to provide key

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to enable SSHing from one EC2 instance to another without a key.

`$ ssh ubuntu@slave` gives me a permsission denied (public key)

Whereas `$ ssh -i aws-key.pem ubuntu@slave` works correctly as expected.

Since I want to enable ssh less logging, I did the following

1) Generated a key in the master instance like

```
 $ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa_master_to_slave
```

2) Added that key to the list of authorized keys of the same master instance

```
 $ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa_master_to_slave.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

3) SCPed the public key file to the slave instance.

```
 $ scp -i aws_key.pem /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa_master_to_slave.pub  ubuntu@slave:~/
```

4) Added the SCP-ed file to the list of authorized keys in the slave instance as well.

```
 $ cat id_dsa_master_to_slave.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Still when I try to SSH without proving the pem file, I get

```
Permission Denied (Public Key)
```

Am I missing out something?

Comment: Can you cut-and-paste in the actual ssh command, for completeness?  It would be nice if it were clear which machine you're sshing from and to.

Comment: @MadHatter I have edited the question.

Comment: How about if you try `ssh -i id_dsa_master_to_slave ubuntu@slave`?

Comment: you need ssh-add ~/aws-key.pem before you ssh to the ubuntu host. This adds your aws-key to your ssh agent. See: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add

Comment: @MadHatter Yes. ssh works with that key as well.

Comment: @dmourati Your answer has fixed the problem. Please "Answer" this question so that I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `ssh-add ~/aws-key.pem` before you ssh to the ubuntu host. This adds your aws-key to your ssh agent. See: [linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one approach is to:

- create a new key pair with `ssh-keygen`
- add the private key to ssh-agent using `ssh-add id_rsa`
- add generated id_rsa.pub with `ssh-copy-id user@host`
- in case ssh-copy-id does not work,

> `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -i ~/.ssh/my.key ubuntu@10.0.0.X "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

Another (bad) approach is to upload to all ec2 instances the `aws-key.pem` key used during the creation of instances. On each instance, we can add this aws-key.pem using `ssh-add aws-key.pem` would enable passwordless ssh between all instances (including localhost). But in this case, every time we log into ec2 we have to repeat this step.

If we need passwordless ssh b/w master and all slaves (i.e., no passwordless ssh between slaves), then we can just `ssh-add aws-key.pem` on master.

A connected issue is when we are trying to setup passwordless ssh between ec2 instances for setting up a HADOOP cluster. From [here,](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts) the master only accesses the slaves via ssh. Slaves do not interact with each other.
Another option from the docs is:

> Note, the master machine accesses each of the worker machines via ssh. By default, ssh is run in parallel and requires password-less (using a private key) access to be setup. If you do not have a password-less setup, you can set the environment variable SPARK_SSH_FOREGROUND and serially provide a password for each worker.